# Add additional options in Properties->C/C++->Command Line using Premake

Tags: visual-studio, premake

I need to add "/FS" to Properties->C/C++->Command Line->Additional Options.

My (shortened) premake.lua:

```
workspace "test_refactor_edit_control_01"
    platforms { "Win32", "64" }
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

    filter "platforms:Win32"
        architecture "x86"

    filter "platforms:64"
        architecture "x64"

project "test_refactor_edit_control_01"
    location "test_refactor_edit_control_01"
    kind "WindowedApp"
    language "C++"
    staticruntime "Off"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

... (Few more things; nothing special)
```

Using Premake5 and VS2019

Comment: https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues/1329

Answer (score 2):

it should be enough to add

```
buildoptions{"/FS"}
```